# Enum is a raw type. References to generic type Enum<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, generics

I am getting the following warning in my java code...

```
Enum is a raw type. References to generic type Enum<E> should be parameterized
```

I am not sure what the proper course of action is to rectify this warning...

My code that triggers the warning is the following class definition on the method *process*...

The implementing classes of this abstract class return varying types of enums, and the user of the Message abstract class simply calls `ordinal()` on the enum, without knowing anything about the underlying type of Enum.

```
public abstract class Message {

    private User user;

    // return string name of message that will be use for factory construction
    public abstract String getName();

    // if set to true, the framework will automatically check for a firebase idToken in the root json node
    // it will then authenticate and call setUser with the internal user.
    // If implementing class set requiresUserAuth to return true, then is it safe to call getUser in the 
    // process method.
    public abstract boolean requiresUserAuth();

    // process the json contents of the message and return the int result code specific for the message
    // populate ObjectNode response with the json response data.        
    public abstract Enum process(JsonNodeThrows contents , ObjectNode response) throws JsonException;
    
    // omit access modifier to use default package protected
    void setUser(User user) 
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    protected User getUser()
    {
        if (!requiresUserAuth())
            throw new RuntimeException("Message.getUser() - called getUser when implementing message class requireUserAuth method returns a value of false.");
        if (user == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Message.getUser() - called getUser when user is null.");
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `Enum<?>`?

Comment: „*the user of the Message abstract class simply calls oridinal() on the enum*“ — I'm assuming by that you mean consumers of the concrete _`Message`_  implementations will not call any other _`Enum`_ methods. Is that right? — „*without knowing anything about the underlying type of Enum*“ — Your app's consumers won't know the underlying types of _`Enum`_. But will ***you***, as the author of the API, have any control over the underlying types of _`Enum`_ your application's API will expose? I proposed a solution that's based on both answers to those two questions being *Yes*. TIA for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If method can return various enums, use

```java
public abstract Enum<?> process(...
```

If the caller knows which enum to expect, use

```java
public abstract <T extends Enum<T>> T process(...
```

Comment: The second one is unsafe, though. The method is saying that it can return whatever type the caller expects, without knowing what that type is.

Answer (score 0):

> *`Enum` is a raw type. `References` to generic type `Enum<E>` should be parameterized…*

[*`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is a generic class*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html). That's what the warning message is referring to by telling you „*`Enum<E>` should be parameterized*“. But that warning is a red herring.

> „*…I am not sure what the proper course of action is to rectify this warning…*“

The design of your *`Message.process()`* method should probably be refactored.

> „*…the user of the Message abstract class **simply calls oridinal()** on the enum, without knowing anything about the underlying type of Enum…*“

If you are certain that *`Enum.ordinal( )`* is all that will ever be called, and if you have control over what *`Enums`* will be exposed in your app's API, then one option you have is to introduce an interface (*an `Ordinalable`, say*) that specifies the *`ordinal()`* method. Then all your app's *`Enums`* could implement *`Ordinalable`* (*or **any** name you want to give it*).

Something like…

```
public interface Ordinalable { 

    int ordinal( );
}

…

enum Foo implements Ordinalable { 
    A, B, C … ;
}

…

enum Bar implements Ordinalable { 

    UNOS, DOS, TRES;

}

…

public abstract class Message { 
    …
    public abstract Ordinalable process( … ){ … }
    …
}

…

public class AMessage extends Message {

    @Override
    public Ordinalable process( ){ 
        return Foo.A;
    }
}

…

public class BMessage extends Message { 

    @Override
    public Ordinalable process( ){ 
        return Foo.B;
    }
}

…

public class DuoMessage extends Message { 

    @Override
    public Ordinalable process( ){ 
        return Bar.DOS;
    }
}
```

…Which can be called like…

```
Message msg = new AMessage( );
    
int ordinal = msg.process( ).ordinal( );
…
msg = new BMessage( );
    
ordinal = msg.process( ).ordinal( );
…
msg = new DuoMessage( );
    
ordinal = msg.process( ).ordinal( );
…
```

You can see [*an experimental implementation of that approach here*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_311210).